# Hide and Show div in same level

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my jsp page like this :
EDIT : http://jsfiddle.net/F4nA9/

```
<div id="fonctiondetails">  
   [...]
   <img onclick="showoption()" ... />
   [...]
</div>
<div id="addqualite" style="display: none;">
   [...]                
</div>
```

And my jQuery function to hide and show my DIVs

```
function showoption() {

    $( "#fonctiondetails" ).hide('slide',1000);
    $( "#addqualite" ).show('slide',1000);

}
```

The problem is that when my first div disappear the second div come from the bottom and go up and replace the first div, but me I want her to display in the same level as the first div and come from the left or the right of the first div.

Comment: plz create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F4nA9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/F4nA9/1/

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

#fonctiondetails {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: @Youssef is this what you need

Comment: You can also use $( "#addqualite" ).css("z-index" ,"1").show('slide',1000);

Answer (score 2):

Your divs must be in same place/level in design;

Think that:

```
<style>
    #fonctiondetails{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    #addqualite{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        display:none;
    } 
</style>
```

In that case, 2 divs are in same place and so while the firs div being disappear, second div will be shown. And they will be no movement effect because they are in the same place.

Example style was to show you the place of div. But you have to design your divs according to your template/page.

Try using position style (absolute, relative, static or fixed)

I think this will be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $( "#addqualite" ).show('slide',1000);
    },200);
```

Comment: it's not a problem of timing.

Comment: thanks @uzor it work also for me :) it seems that there is many way to make that like ;)

Comment: i just have to set the time parameter to 600 like `setTimeout(function(){
        $( "#addqualite" ).show('slide',1000);
    },600);`

Answer (score 0):

I made my own solution, I create a container div like this:

```
<div id="animateslide">
    <div id="fonctiondetails"> ... </div>           
    <div id="addqualite" > ... </div>
</div>
```

and css file like this:

```
#animateslide {
   position: relative;
   [...] /* it's good to specify a height of your choice */
}

#fonctiondetails {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   [...]
}

#addqualite{
   position: absolute; /* even if we did'nt specify position it's work */
   [...]
}
```